# MySQL: How to copy column of same table to another column with unix time convert

Tags: mysql

I got my solution on SO on how to copy data from a column to another column but I need to convert the "from column" unix to the datetime column. `ColumnA` is of type int and `ColumnB` is of type TIMESTAMP:

```sql
UPDATE foods
SET 
  ColumnB = FROM_UNIXTIME(ColumnA, '%Y %M %D %H:%i:%s')
WHERE
  ColumnB IS NULL
```

If ColumnA's value is `1633711068`, after running the code, ColumnB becomes `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. Any reason?

I'm not a DBA, I'm just learning as I go along with a codebase I've inherited.

Comment: What datatype does column `ColumnB` have ? (In other words, what is the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE foods`)

Comment: Sorry. It's `TIMESTAMP`. I've updated the post.

Comment: The function [FROM_UNIXTIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) returns a representation of unix_timestamp as a datetime or character string value.   When it returns a string value, you cannot use it to update a timestamp field.

Comment: So my only solution is to create a php  function to loop through and update the column? I'm using PHP as the backend.

Comment: Remove the format argument '%Y %M %D %H:%i:%s' from FROM_UNIXTIME().

Comment: @forpas ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️ Thank you!

Comment: @sylar Luuk's comment is meant to lead to the same conclusion as Forpas' comment. By including your own formatting string you're creating a string that's incompatible with conversion to timestamp.  That incompatible string is resulting in a 0 timestamp.  Leaving the formatting string empty returns a datetime, rather than a string. It's all in the manual (which Luuk linked for you too) ; https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime